# Regex similar to parsing function parameters e.g. foo(var, bar) and getting var in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

If I have something a string that looks like "TEST(10,20,30)" how would I be able to pull just the 10 out of this string.

I have tried

```
/\(([^\)]+)\)/
```

and that gets the inside of the parenthesis, but when I trie to add in a comma e.g.

```
/\(([^\),]+)\)/
```

then nothing matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you need to tell the regex to match the stuff between your comma and the closing bracket, too (or leave it out):

```
/\(([^),]+)/
```

or

```
/\(([^),]+)[^)]*\)/
```

As you can see you also don't need to escape parentheses inside character classes.

Comment: i guess u have complicated it a bit ;)

Comment: I just tried to keep close to the original attempt, to make it easily understandable. But yeah, there are better solutions ;)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the pattern of the part you want to pick up is much simpler than the pattern of the part that you want to throw out.

```
"TEST(10,20,30)"[/\d+/] # => 10
```

Answer (score 1):

> how would I be able to pull just the 10 out of this string.

Use `lookahead` and `lookbehind`

```
(?<=\()\d+(?=,)
```

works [here](http://fiddle.re/dkm5)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can guide you in the right direction:

```
irb(main):001:0> str = "TEST(10,20,30)"
=> "TEST(10,20,30)"
irb(main):002:0> str =~ /\w+\(([^,]+),.+\)/
=> 0
irb(main):003:0> $~[1]
=> "10"
```

The regex does this:
**\w+**
One or more word characters ("TEST")

**(([^,]+)**
A group for anything that is not a comma, this will match everything from the left paranthesis to the comma.

The rest of the regex ignores the other parameters, but it could be modified to include them in separate groups.